# How to position bootstrap glyphicon on top of another absolute positioned div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am drawing a triangle on a card and want to place a glyphicon on top of it. The triangle and great, and the glyph shows up... but always below and never on top of. I have tried wrapping the glpyh in a relative dive and making the glyph absolute,  using top and left positioning, all to no avail.

The basics are (jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/joshuaohana/4pgjcr47/):

```
<div class="triangle">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>          
</div>

.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 85px 85px 0 0;
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

My only complication is that triangle needs to stay absolute.
How can I position the glyphicon inside the middle of the triangle?

Comment: Do you need the Span to be inside the Div?

Comment: haha no and now I feel dumb, thank you @LeonFreire :) Working great now by keeping out outside of the div andp ositioning it like normal. If you want to post this as an answer I will accept it

Comment: Thank you! Posted an answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may put the Span outside of the the Div and it will work fine with your absolute positioning! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative `top` value:
https://jsfiddle.net/4pgjcr47/8/

```
.triangle > span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  top: -65px;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems:

First the specificity of your css selector is not specific enough, so you don't overwrite the top set by the css for the glyphicon

Second, your top should be minus as you are using borders to draw a triangle (so the top is outside the actual triangle div).

Try the below css and it should solve both problems:

```css
span.glyphicon {      // more specific selector
  position: absolute;
  top: -65px;         // move up over border
  left: 20px;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pgjcr47/7/)

[More information on css specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="triangle">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>          
</div>

.triangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 85px 85px 0 0;
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

Never use a div and div which are both absolute!

Comment: Why should you "*Never use a div and div which are both absolute*"?  What about a close button that is position absolutely in the top right of an absolutely positioned modal popup? and just changing from absolute to relative doesn't do anything - the initial problem is still there

Answer (score -1):

Span: Modify the top position with negative values, where the -85px corresponds to the size of the container div. For the example use -70px.

```
.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 85px 85px 0 0;
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
}

span.glyphicon-exclamation-sign {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  top: -70px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```